# Matrix spectral decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix $(N \times N)$ and $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose A has N eigenvalues $\lambda_{1} < \lambda_{2} < ...\lambda_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$.
$A$ = $R \Omega R^{-1}$ its  spectral decomposition, where $R$ is the matrix with columns consist of right  eigenvectors, $\Omega $  is the diagonal matrix of corresponding eigenvalues.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&A = A^{+} + A^{-}\\
&A^{+} = R \Omega^{+} R^{-1}\\
&A^{-} = R \Omega^{-} R^{-1}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

$ \Omega^{+} = 0.5 (\Omega + |\Omega|), \Omega^{+} = 0.5 (\Omega - |\Omega|)$.  I need to obtain matrix $A^{+}$ and $A^{-}$. Does anybody know how to do it without finding all eigenvalues and eigenvectors if it is possible? 
Numerical solution of problem is also considered.

Comment: You can't say it's diagonal like that. Either you suppose it or you replace $\le$ by $<$ to ensure that the eigenvalues are distinct. And what do you mean by $|X|$ for $X$ a matrix? The matrix whose elements are the module of the element of the other matrix?

Comment: I have replaced inequalities. Now there is no ambiguity. Yes, elements of |X| are the modules of the corresponding elements of X.